# Parse maillog in python

Tags: python

I am stuck a bit with my task :)
I have maillog like :

```
Oct  3 15:30:18 mail1 postfix/lmtp[5369]: DB10242054: to=<XXXXX>, orig_to=<XXXXXX>, relay=ip[ip]:port, delay=1.4, delays=0.04/0/0.01/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[iP]:port): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4580B4208C)
Oct  3 15:30:18 mail1 postfix/smtp[5175]: 4580B4208C: to=<XXXXX>, relay=XXXXX[IP]:port, delay=0.52, delays=0.02/0.01/0.27/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1412343018 rr9si6866736lbb - gsmtp)
Oct  3 15:33:57 mail1 amavis[5542]: (05542-09) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [ip]:port [ip] <XXXX> -> <XXX>, Message-ID: <XXX>, mail_id: XXXXX, Hits: -1.899, size: 6483, queued_as: 806A24207B, 1483 ms
Oct  3 15:33:57 mail1 postfix/lmtp[6694]: F1FDD41F9D: to=<XXXXXX>, orig_to=<BBBBBB>, relay=ip[ip]:port, delay=1.7, delays=0.18/0/0.01/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 806A24207B)
```

I need to print:

```
message from: 
message to:
sent at:
status:
```

one "transaction" in maillog has unique id, but that id can appear in different places in the file.
My idea:

- first search single email-address in the file;
- "save" all matched rows in new list (so then I can iterate over smaller list);

But I have no idea, how can I parse next?
My code now looks:

```
lines = []
queue_id = []
f_h = open('/path_to_/maillog', 'r')

def Find_Email(pattern,text):
    email = re.search(pattern, text)
    if email:
        lines.append(text)
        q_id = re.search('[A-F0-9]{10}', text)
        print text,
        if q_id:
            queue_id.append(q_id.group())


for line in f_h:
    Find_Email(r'recipient@gmil.com',line)
```

I do  not ask for code :)
But could you please share some ideas if you have such experience ?

Huge thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I promised,
I am adding complete variant of parser. The code is not clean but I do not see the way how I can improve it now.
You can use it as parser.py mail 10:06 - it will filter maillog on timestamp

import re, sys

```
email_pattern = sys.argv[1]
file = '/var/log/maillog'
timestamp = sys.argv[2]


def client(line):
    client = re.search(r'(client=)([\w\d\.-]+[\w\d\.-]\[[\d]{1,3}\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3}\]))', line)
    if client:
        print re.search('(\w{3}[^a-zA-Z]+)+', line).group(), re.search('([A-F0-9]{10})(:)', line).group(1), '[Client connected from ip]:' , client.group(2)

def message_id(line):
    msg_id=re.search(r'message-id=<([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)>', line)
    if msg_id:
        print re.search('(\w{3}[^a-zA-Z]+)+', line).group(), re.search('([A-F0-9]{10})(:)', line).group(1), "[Header]:", msg_id.group()

def message_from(line):
    sender = re.search('(from=<)([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)(>)', line)
    number_of_recepients = re.search('(nrcpt=)(\d)',line)
    if sender: print re.search('(\w{3}[^a-zA-Z]+)+', line).group(), re.search('([A-F0-9]{10})(:)', line).group(1), "[Sender]:", sender.group(2)
    if number_of_recepients: print '[Number of recepients]:', number_of_recepients.group(2)

def message_to(line):
    receiver = re.search('(to=<)([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)(>)', line)
    delays = re.search(r'(delays=)([\d+.\d.]+)([\/])([\d+.\d.]+)([\/])([\d+.\d.]+)([\/])([\d+.\d.]+)',line)
    if receiver: print re.search('(\w{3}[^a-zA-Z]+)+', line).group(), re.search('([A-F0-9]{10})(:)', line).group(1), "[Receiver]:", receiver.group(2), '\n[Postfix status]:'
    if delays:
        print '\t[Time before queue manager, including message transmission]:', delays.group(2), '\n','\t[Time in queue manager]:', delays.group(4),\
            '\n','\t[Conn setup time including DNS, HELO and TLS]:', delays.group(6), '\n', '\t[Message transmission time]:',delays.group(8),'\n','\t[Status of the message]:', line.split(',')[5:]

def status(line):
    status = re.search('removed', line)
    if status:
        print re.search('(\w{3}[^a-zA-Z]+)+', line).group(), re.search('([A-F0-9]{10})(:)', line).group(1), "[Message status in postfix queue]:", status.group()

# Find transaction id
key_ids = []
def find_transaction_id(line):
    if len(timestamp)>1:
        if re.search(timestamp, line):
            from_ = re.search(r'(postfix/qmgr\[\d*\]: )([A-F0-9]{10})(: from=<)([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)(>)', line)
            to_ = re.search(r'(postfix/lmtp\[\d*\]: )([A-F0-9]{10})(: to=<)([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)(>)', line)
            if (from_) and (from_.group(2) not in key_ids): 
                key_ids.append(from_.group(2))
                sender_stat.append(from_.group(3))
            elif (to_) and (to_.group(2) not in key_ids): 
                key_ids.append(to_.group(2))
                receiver_stat.append(to_.group(3))
        else:
            pass
    else:
        from_ = re.search(r'(postfix/qmgr\[\d*\]: )([A-F0-9]{10})(: from=<)([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)(>)', line)
        to_ = re.search(r'(postfix/lmtp\[\d*\]: )([A-F0-9]{10})(: to=<)([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+)(>)', line)
        if (from_) and (from_.group(2) not in key_ids): 
           key_ids.append(from_.group(2))
        elif (to_) and (to_.group(2) not in key_ids): 
           key_ids.append(to_.group(2))

# Find transaction ids
fh = open(file, 'r')
for line in fh:
        if re.search(email_pattern, line):
            find_transaction_id(line)
fh.close()

matches = len(key_ids)
if matches > 0:
    print "This mailbox was found ", matches, " times as Sender\Receiver\n"
    print '**************************************'
else:
    print sys.exit("Matches not  found")

# Find all events related to that transaction ids elem in line
for elem in key_ids:
    for line in open(file,'r'):
        current_id = re.search(r'([A-F0-9]{10})(:)', line)
        if current_id and (elem == current_id.group(1)):
            client(line)
            message_id(line)
            message_from(line)
            message_to(line)
            status(line)
    print '**************************************'


print "\nI am done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to identify what can be the last line in the log for a transaction. Then you define a class for the elements you want in a transaction, and a `dict` { transaction_id : transaction } and iterate you log :

- get a line and find transaction id
- if transaction id not in dict, add it to the dict
- get current transaction by its id and update it
- if current line is a last line

  - output the transaction
  - remove it from dict
- if no more lines in maillog, iterate dict

  - output current status of transaction
  - remove it from dict

That is only the general algorythm, but it would be necessary to know more on your mail config to give real code

Answer (score 0):

First things first -- you're on the right track by wanting to narrow the lines down to just the ones that have the email that you're looking for. However, you can handle this directly within your function, without having to deal with the `lines` and `queue_id` lists.

What I would do is modify the purpose of your `find_email` function (note that it is common practice in Python for function names to be lowercase) so that it is looking for a particular email address, and if it finds it in a given line, then instead of adding the line and q_id to lists, it calls other functions to search the line for the additional parts and print them. I've written some (pseudo)code below to illustrate what I mean.

Another thing: It looks like there are a couple lines that have `"queued as XXXXXXXXXX"` at the end of the line -- I'm assuming that you want to ignore the first q_id and use the one at the end, right? Your function to parse the q_id can look something like this:

```
def parse_q_id(text):
    queued_as = re.search(r'queued as ([A-F0-9]{10})', text):
    if queued_as is not None:
        return queued_as.group()
    else:
        q_id = re.search(r'[A-FO-9]{10}', text)
        if q_id is not None:
            return q_id.group()
        else:
            return "not found"
```

Notice the use of a group within that first regular expression to easily pull the q_id out of the string "queued as (q_id here)". You can use this pattern for each field as needed.

One more thing: whenever you open a resource like a file, you are responsible for closing it once you're done with it. The best way to do this is a [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Here is an idea of how you could lay out your program:

```
def find_email(pattern, text):
    for line in text:
        email = re.search(pattern, line)
        if email is not None:
            print "message from:", message_from(line)
            print "message to:", message_to(line)
            print "sent at:", sent_at(line)
            print "status:", status(line)
            print "queue id:", parse_q_id(line)

# The four functions below should return either what you're looking for, or something
# like "not found."

def message_from(line):
    # write me

def message_to(line):
    # write me

def sent_at(line):
    # write me

def status(line):
    # write me

def parse_q_id(line):
    queued_as = re.search(r'queued as ([A-F0-9]{10})', text):
    if queued_as is not None:
        return queued_as.group()
    else:
        q_id = re.search(r'[A-FO-9]{10}', text)
        if q_id is not None:
            return q_id.group()
        else:
            return "not found"

with open('/path_to_/maillog') as f:
    data = f.read()
    find_email("test@example.com", data)
```

You might want to store your results instead of printing them, in which case I would recommend a dictionary:

```
def find_email(pattern, text):
    result = {}

    ...

    if email is not None:
        result["from"] = message_from(line)
        result["to"] = message_to(line)
        result["sent at"] = sent_at(line)
        result["status"] = status(line)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Queue id can be different :

When a message enters the Postfix system,  it is immediately assigned a queue ID -
the message id of the currently processed email. 
Once a message has reached the incoming queue the next hop is to deliver it. That would be second messages id.

It is like a two transactions of one action.

Answer (score -1):

All lines seem to have a standard format, so regexes and split()s will do the trick.